# DRF - limit objects returned to owner

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('MyappUser', related_name='Myapp_owner')
    list = models.ForeignKey('WidgetList')
```

What I want to be able to do is when calling a specific view -

```
class WidgetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer
    filter_class = WidgetFilter
```

I only want the widgets owned by the user logged in.

My current filter is -

```
class WidgetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    owner = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="owner", lookup_type="exact")
    list = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="list", lookup_type="exact")

    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ['owner', 'list']
```

Right now I have to do `/api/widgets/?owner=3&list=5`

But that doesn't prevent another user from viewing the widget.

I had previously been doing it using the following but it breaks my ability to do a filter class -

```
class WidgetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer


    def get(self, request):
        if request.user:
            queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(owner=request.user)
            for object in queryset:
                object.code = decrypt_code(masterkey,
                                                   personalkey,
                                                   object.code)
        else:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = WidgetSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

What I want to be able to do is if I have a list like this -

```
Jane
Widget 1
Widget List ABC

Jane
Widget 2
Widget List DEF (which is 3)

Mike (which is 3)
Widget 3
Widget List ABC (which is 5)

Alfred
Widget 4
Widget List ABC
```

if I do `/api/widgets/?list=5` if I'm logged in as Mike I only want to see Widget 3

Comment: Override `get_queryset` and keep the filter_class.

Comment: explain how?  I've been trying 15 different things with no luck.

Comment: Writing an elaborate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note that you can use both an overridden `.get_queryset()` and generic
>   filtering together, and everything will work as expected.

So I would do something like:

```
class WidgetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer
    filter_class = WidgetFilter


    def get_queryset(self):
        owner = self.request.user
        return super(WidgetList, self).get_queryset().filter(owner=request.user)
```

I didn't manage to test the code however my expectation is that `get_queryset` would only return the entries filtered by owner. So it will not contain entries from other users.

Comment: But this is what I'm already doing with my working example?  The problem is then trying to do a filter isn't doing anything.

`    def get(self, request):
        if request.user:
            queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(owner=request.user)`?

Comment: Because you skipped the `filter_class` on `WidgetList`?

Comment: I think I know the problem.  I need to have the other code in there to get the return as it's decrypting data in a field.  your code works, the problem is where do I put the `for object in queryset: ....` which needs to be there to decrypt the field object.code?

Comment: What happens when you add the `filter_class` on the 2nd example? I see no `filter_class` here - http://imgur.com/MKIyMCc

Comment: BTW, IMO, the decryption should go to the model and then you should use it in the serializer.

Comment: ah thnx!  Yeah I was never sure where to put the decryption however the decryption is based on the user logged in would that still work in the model?